# Displaying Xs and Os for C# tic tac toe

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a simple tic tac toe program for class. I know there are other posts on the site responding to similar course work but I can't find the help I need. I have a 2d array set up for my grid. I have 9 labels to hold the random generated 0 or 1 to represent the X(1) or O(0). My issue is that I am unsure of how to display an X or an O instead of the number. Also, I have a several lines set to check if X or O won, however, I don't know how to show if it is a tie. I am not looking for a direct answer but guidance on how to accomplish this. As of right now, my form will display random 1s and 0s and if the conditions are met will state if X or O won, but it does this even if X or O did not win. There is no human element to this game other than to click the button that calls the function to generate the numbers and update the form. My code is as follows:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TicTacToe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void playAgain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            const int rows = 3;
            const int columns = 3;
            int[,] board = new int[rows, columns];

            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
                {
                    board[row, col] = rand.Next(2);
                }
            }

            square1.Text = board[0, 0].ToString();
            square2.Text = board[0, 1].ToString();
            square3.Text = board[0, 2].ToString();
            square4.Text = board[1, 0].ToString();
            square5.Text = board[1, 1].ToString();
            square6.Text = board[1, 2].ToString();
            square7.Text = board[2, 0].ToString();
            square8.Text = board[2, 1].ToString();
            square9.Text = board[2, 2].ToString();

            //O win check
            if (board[0,0] == 0 && (board[0,0] == board[0,1]) && (board[0,1] == board[0,2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
            }
            else if (board[1, 0] == 0 && (board[1, 0] == board[1, 1]) && (board[1, 1] == board[1, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
            }
            else if (board[2, 0] == 0 && (board[2, 0] == board[2, 1]) && (board[2, 1] == board[2, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 0] == 0 && (board[0, 0] == board[1, 0]) && (board[1, 0] == board[2, 0]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 1] == 0 && (board[0, 1] == board[1, 1]) && (board[1, 1] == board[2, 1]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 2] == 0 && (board[0, 2] == board[1, 2]) && (board[1, 2] == board[2, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 0] == 0 && (board[0, 0] == board[1, 1]) && (board[1, 1] == board[2, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 2] == 0 && (board[0, 2] == board[1, 1]) && (board[0, 1] == board[2, 0]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
            }


            //X win check
            if (board[0, 0] == 1 && (board[0, 0] == board[0, 1]) && (board[0, 1] == board[0, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
            }
            else if (board[1, 0] == 1 && (board[1, 0] == board[1, 1]) && (board[1, 1] == board[1, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
            }
            else if (board[2, 0] == 1 && (board[2, 0] == board[2, 1]) && (board[2, 1] == board[2, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 0] == 1 && (board[0, 0] == board[1, 0]) && (board[1, 0] == board[2, 0]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 1] == 1 && (board[0, 1] == board[1, 1]) && (board[1, 1] == board[2, 1]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 2] == 1 && (board[0, 2] == board[1, 2]) && (board[1, 2] == board[2, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 0] == 1 && (board[0, 0] == board[1, 1]) && (board[1, 1] == board[2, 2]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
            }
            else if (board[0, 2] == 1 && (board[0, 2] == board[1, 1]) && (board[0, 1] == board[2, 0]))
            {
                winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
            }
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array is defined as an int.  From : int[,] board = new int[rows, columns]; To: string[,] board = new string[rows, columns];

Comment: Worked like a charm for the Xs and Os.

Comment: I spoke to soon @jdweng. I reread the instructions and it states I must use a 2d int array. So I am back to square one. I tried an if/else and converted rand.Next to a string and compared it to 0. If it equals that, it is an "O" else it is an "X". But I the error that it cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.

Comment: Then use this for example : square1.Text = board[0, 0] == 0 ? "O" : "X";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the hints you want.

When you assign the board item to the label text convert it to X or O:

```
square1.Text = board[0, 0] == 0 ? "O" : "X";

//In the check if O wins record the winning text in a string instead of winnerBox.Text. 

string oWinsText == string.Empty;

if (board[0,0] == 0 && (board[0,0] == board[0,1]) && (board[0,1] == board[0,2])) { 
   oWinsText = "O wins!"; }

//Then do the same in the check if X wins:
string xWinsText == string.Empty;

if (board[0,0] == 0 && (board[0,0] == board[0,1]) && (board[0,1] == board[0,2])) { 
   xWinsText = "X wins!"; }

//Check if it's a draw:
bool isDraw = (oWinsText.Length > 0 && xWinsText.Length > 0);

//Finally show the result
if (isDraw)
  winnerBox.Text = "Draw";
else
  winnerBox.Text = oWinsText + xWinsText;
```

Comment: Storing the results in a string and comparing length helped tons! I am having a curious issue. For example all of column 0 has O and all of row 2 has O but it calls a draw. I am not sure how you would regulate that.

Comment: You should do a 5 minute video tutorial on Debugging, it will help you to see the problem by stepping through the code. It's an invaluable tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private Random rand = new Random();

private void playAgain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[][] squares = new TextBox[][]
    {
        new TextBox[] { square1, square2, square3 },
        new TextBox[] { square4, square5, square6 },
        new TextBox[] { square7, square8, square9 },
    };

    const int rows = 3;
    const int columns = 3;
    char[,] board = new char[rows, columns];

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
        {
            board[row, col] = rand.Next(2) == 0 ? 'O' : 'X';
            squares[row][col].Text = board[row, col].ToString();
        }
    }

    var scoring =
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, 3)
            .SelectMany(n => new[]
            {
                Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => board[n, x]),
                Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => board[x, n]),
            })
            .Concat(new[]
            {
                Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => board[x, x]),
                Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => board[x, 2 - x]),
            })
            .Select(xs => String.Join("", xs))
            .ToLookup(x => x);

    int xwins = scoring["XXX"].Count();
    int owins = scoring["OOO"].Count();

    if (xwins == 1 & owins == 0)
    {
        winnerBox.Text = "X wins!";
    }
    else if (xwins == 0 && owins == 1)
    {
        winnerBox.Text = "O wins!";
    }
    else if (xwins == 0 && owins == 0)
    {
        winnerBox.Text = "Draw";
    }
    else
    {
        winnerBox.Text = "Invalid Game";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great but far too advanced for my level of skill. Someday though